# Puppeteer | Download octet-stream file

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, http, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeteer to bypass cloudflare security.
Long story short, I need to perform a `POST` request that launches some kind of binary file download. Actually, this file is just a plain text that being sent without extension like this for some reason *(separated by `\n`)* and can be easily opened with any text editor:

```
{ json string 1 }
{ json string 2 }
...
```

**W**hen this request is being performed by a normal browser *(when site is being used as it should be)*, it just fetches this url, waits for it's response, and text is being displayed on the page. Response itself can be seen in DevTools as a plain text with `application/octet-stream` header.
**W**hen I try to fetch it with a Puppeteer using `GoToAsync` in **non-headless** mode, it waits for response, then starts downloading it as a binary file with a chromium dowload manager, and, before download is even finished, instantly throws `NavigationException: net::ERR_ABORTED`, but download continues normally. That's ok, I understand that it's just some kind of a bug, and I actually still can handle it with `try-catch` and then access received data by opening a downloaded file *(though, it would be much better to get it as a `Stream` or a plain text from response itself somehow)*.
**P**roblem is that I need to use Puppeteer in **headless mode**. In headless, it acts absolutely same but **download just won't start**. What can I do with it? Can I at least download it somehow, ignoring this exception the same way as in non-headless mode?

Here's a schematic code sample I use:

```cs
var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync();
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new() { Headless = true });
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);
await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new
{
    behavior = "allow",
    downloadPath = "_path_"
});

page.Request += async (s, e) =>
{
    // sets method to POST, adds some headers, specifies post-data
    var payloadOverride = new Payload() { ... };
    await e.Request.ContinueAsync(payloadOverride); // executes normally and leaves code block
};

var response = await page.GoToAsync($"url"); // will throw exception "somewhere in await"
```

Also, I've tried to do something like this:

```cs
page.Response+= async (s, e) =>
{
    await e.Response.TextAsync();
    await e.Response.JsonAsync();
    await e.Response.BufferAsync();
};
```

When `GoToAsync`, `.Response` event is actually being triggered normally *(right in moment before `net::ERR_ABORTED` thorws up)*, but these methods will just throw `PuppeteerSharp.BufferException: "Unable to get response body"`. So, I can't get data from here, as I hoped to.

Also, I've tried to use `Evaulate` to `fetch()` it from browser itself, but cloudflare won't allow me to. Though, it (`fetch(...).then((response) => response.text())`) works in the console of my normal browser and successfully returns expected text string, as in example in the very beginning of the topic, but only if I first go to the site itself and open DevTools there. I've tried to `GoTo` to it with a Puppeteer and then `Evaulate` it there, but got 1020 Access Denied.
Few weeks ago, before cloudflare have updated something, I was simply using `HttpClient` with a proper User Agent header. This code was looking like this and worked absolutely fine:

```cs
HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, "same url");
// ...setting post-data and headers...
var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

// => It will return simple text with few lines, as in example in beginning
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
string[] chunks = content.Split("\n"); // => and here I have array of JSON string ["{ }", "{ }", ...]
```

Any advise would be appreciated. I use `.NET` version of Puppeteer, but it's ok if your examples will be wrote with `JS` as I know that node version is way more popular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solutions I have found so far:**

#### First:

Just use `Puppeteer Stealth Plugin` and JS `fetch()` in `EvaluateFunctionAsync()`. Yes, it was that simple.

#### Second:

That's what I was using before I knew about stealth plugin.

```cs
string someDownloadPath = "";
var page = await _browser.NewPageAsync();
await page.SetRequestInterceptionAsync(true);

// allows regular downloads for a headless mode
await page.Client.SendAsync("Page.setDownloadBehavior", new { behavior = "allow", someDownloadPath });

// sending POST with GoToAsync
page.Request += (s, requestArgs) => YourContinueRequestHandler(requestArgs, HttpMethod.Post, data);

// it will ALWAYS throw an exception
try { await page.GoToAsync(url); }
catch (NavigationException)
{
    // puppeteer will download content as a binary file with a "download" name
    string responsePath = $"{someDownloadPath}/download";

    // Wait 30 seconds for a response to download
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        if (File.Exists(responsePath)) break;
    }
    var content = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(responsePath);
}
```